# Xcode Swift iBeacon ranging from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am doing startRangingBeaconsInRegion in AppDelegate
Once the beacon is detected ... Main View Controller -> goes to -> ABC ViewController and I want to stop the ranging until the user clicks a 'Back' button. 
How can I stop the ranging from the new ViewController ABC ? And when 'Back' button is pressed, to start ranging again?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to stop ranging for beacons while the `ABCViewController` is active, you can add two methods in your `AppDelegate` like this:

```
func stopRanging() {
  locationManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
}

func startRanging() {
  locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
}
```

Then in your `ABCViewController` you can add methods like this, which will cause ranging to be stopped whenever the view controller is shown and restarted again whenever it is not visible:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.stopRanging()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.startRanging()
}
```

Comment: thank you. Just what i needed. That's why you they call you the beacon Guru :)